# jQuery validation on textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea

I have this code inside a form of mine:

```
<textarea>Your message</textarea>
```

The html content of the  tag will be emptied on focus.

I want to run some validation on this field with jQuery. First, the value of this field should not be = "". Secondly, the content of the  tag should not be = "Your message".

Anyone knows how I can archive this in the most efficient way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validating a <textarea> with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091330/validating-a-textarea-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using jQuery validation plugin which can be found at [bassisance.de](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var form=$(this);
    var text=form.find('textarea');
    if(text!="" && text!="Your message"){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
    });
```